Unity project cannot be built for Android due to a Gradle error
i want to build my unity project for android and got the following error. Building the project for iOS works without any problems
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\MyGames\Projekte\NewGame\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 76

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Could not read script 'D:\MyGames\Projekte\NewGame\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\unityLibrary\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib\packaging_options.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I think the problem is, that the file packaging_options.gradle does not exist in my prject. But how can that be? How do I get the file?

When file packaging_options.gradle cannot be found, how about to create it?
Or got to line 76 and remove that apply statement, when no options required.
The least required content would be: android.packagingOptions {}.

Thanks for the hint. I could create a file with the name, but I don't know the contents. Do you know it?

Can't you read? The answer features the content as well, while even an empty file should suffice to avoid the error. These options vary a lot, depending on the project.
